# How i can display customer balance on sale orders in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to display **customer balance** in sale orders but don't know how to do that. Also i want to display customer's **credit limit** and **next payment date**. Anybody have idea how i can do that, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it by related fields as follow.

**Balance Field :**

```
customer_balance = fields.Float(related="partner_id.credit",string="Balance")
```

**Credit Limit**

```
customer_credit_limit = fields.Float(related="partner_id.credit_limit",string="Credit Limit")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, That's Good